# jQuery browser detection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Is there a good way to detect if the user's browser is Internet Explorer using jQuery?

I have an issue with PNG graphics using IE and want to swap them for GIF's only if the user is viewing the site with IE.

Comment: whats the issue you have with pngs? it would probably be better to use php or something similar server side to swap the graphics depending on browser type. a) more reliable and b) will work for people with no javascript.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson, There is actually no reliable way of doing this server side.

Comment: the annoying blue backgrounds in ie6, I have a striped background box and want to use a png over the top as a Gif doesn't display correctly

Comment: Paul... if its easier i've posted some code that I use which acctually gets round the problem with transparent pngs in ie6. Mattias what about $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']? and its more reliable because it will work on all browsers with all settings.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson, It isn't reliable as the user can easily change it.

Comment: yeah, but if the user changes it they're looking for a different outcome... you should still base your website around it. If a user changes it they know different things would happen, especially with something like this where you're just looking for ie6.

Comment: From what I have gathered looking at the comments, $.support is recommended but it just looks at the ability to support opacity in styling. What if I need to do specific tasks like display the correct browser logo depending on what browser is being used currently. Can this be achieved using $.support or would browser detection be the desired way to go?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You *can* using [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/), yes, but it's a bad idea to use browser detection:

```
if($.browser.msie) { /* IE */ }
```

A better option for instance would be [`$.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) which is *feature* detection, like this:

```
if(!$.support.opacity) { /* IE 6-8 */ }
```

`$.support.opacity` is false in browsers that don't support `opacity` in styling (though IE 7-8 handle transparent PNGs file, so this still isn't ideal, depending on what you're after...personally I think you'd be giving IE 7/8 users a sub-optimal experience).

What you should *really* do is target IE6 which *doesn't* support transparent PNGs (without an alpha filter), like this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE6ImageStyles.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Cheers for the advice Nick,  agree its better to just target ie6.

Comment: have to have the jquery migrate plugin for jquery >1.9 for this to work. as this approach is deprecated

Comment: Yes, this was appropriate as the accepted answer at one time but is no longer (It's Jquery's fault, not Nick's).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can, but they prefer you to use `jQuery.support`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/.

In this case, use `jQuery.support.opacity`.

Edit: assuming this is about opacity, of course.

Answer (score 3):

$.browser has been removed in **1.9** as it's now suggested feature detection was preferred via $.support

Answer (score 2):

For better browser detection jQuery strongly recommend the use of an external library such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/) instead of dependency on properties in [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) or the deprecated [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) (removed since v1.9)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.browser.webkit
$.browser.safari
$.browser.opera
$.browser.msie
$.browser.mozilla

if ($.browser.msie) {
        //do something
}
else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
        //do something else
}
```

works with jQuery 1.3

Comment: "We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery."

Comment: also, your `== true` is redundant. Simply calling `if ($.browser.msie) { }` would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) function.

To detect IE, you can also and better go for [IE conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

**Example:**

```
<!--[if IE]>
  Special instructions for IE here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: "We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery."

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val) {
      $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>")
                .appendTo(document.body);
    });</script>
```

$.browser.msie 
 for IE

Comment: Thanks Simer, think I'll go for just targeting ie6 though.

Answer (score -1):

I realise this isn't an answer  - but I can't really post this in a comment!

If you're going to use javascript this code fixes the png issue with ie6. I haven't used it much, but afaik you need a transparent gif image called x.gif and it does the rest automatically.

```
// JavaScript Document

var supersleight    = function() {

    var root = false;
    var applyPositioning = true;

    // Path to a transparent GIF image
    var shim            = 'x.gif';

    // RegExp to match above GIF image name
    var shim_pattern    = /x\.gif$/i;



    var fnLoadPngs = function() { 
        if (root) {
            root = document.getElementById(root);
        }else{
            root = document;
        }
        for (var i = root.all.length - 1, obj = null; (obj = root.all[i]); i--) {
            // background pngs
            if (obj.currentStyle.backgroundImage.match(/\.png/i) !== null) {
                bg_fnFixPng(obj);
            }
            // image elements
            if (obj.tagName=='IMG' && obj.src.match(/\.png$/i) !== null){
                el_fnFixPng(obj);
            }
            // apply position to 'active' elements
            if (applyPositioning && (obj.tagName=='A' || obj.tagName=='INPUT') && obj.style.position === ''){
                obj.style.position = 'relative';
            }
        }
    };

    var bg_fnFixPng = function(obj) {
        var mode = 'scale';
        var bg  = obj.currentStyle.backgroundImage;
        var src = bg.substring(5,bg.length-2);
        if (obj.currentStyle.backgroundRepeat == 'no-repeat') {
            mode = 'crop';
        }
        obj.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + src + "', sizingMethod='" + mode + "')";
        obj.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+shim+')';
    };

    var el_fnFixPng = function(img) {
        var src = img.src;
        img.style.width = img.width + "px";
        img.style.height = img.height + "px";
        img.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + src + "', sizingMethod='scale')";
        img.src = shim;
    };

    var addLoadEvent = function(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
                if (oldonload) {
                    oldonload();
                }
                func();
            };
        }
    };

    return {
        init: function() { 
            addLoadEvent(fnLoadPngs);
        },

        limitTo: function(el) {
            root = el;
        },

        run: function() {
            fnLoadPngs();
        }
    };
}();

// limit to part of the page ... pass an ID to limitTo:
// supersleight.limitTo('header');

supersleight.init();
```