# Check for IE compatibility jquery

Tags: jquery

To check if user is using IE should this work :

```
if( $.browser.msie)
alert('in IE');
```

Is this applicable to all versions of IE ?

Comment: test..? but generally browser detection using js is a bad idea [citation needed]

Comment: it should, but what's the question exactly?

Comment: Hi, Why not try simple IE browser detection query like this `<!--[if IE]>
  Special instructions for IE here
<![endif]-->]-->` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498057/jquery-browser-detectionl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on which version of jQuery you're using, `$.browser` is deprecated. You should read the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) fore more informations. Use `$.support` for test browser comptability.

Answer (score 1):

Is this applicable to all versions of IE ?

**Yes,** it is applicable to all versions of IE *(I've just tested on ie7, ie8, ie9, which you should have)*

***Its not at all recommended***, from the jQuery docs itself,

Because [$.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) uses `navigator.userAgent` to determine the platform, it is vulnerable to spoofing by the user or misrepresentation by the browser itself. It is always best to avoid browser-specific code entirely where possible. The [$.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) property is available for detection of support for particular features rather than relying on $.browser.