# Choose a link depending on the used browser

Tags: php, javascript, browser, download

For a banner with a download link I want to conditionally add more then 1 link

If the user has Internet Explorer it will show the download link for Internet Explorer 
And if the user has Google Chrome or Safari it should display the link for that browser

Comment: Look up Browser/UA sniffing.

Comment: search for "javascript browser detection" - should be plenty of resources out there.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to get browser info in PHP:

```
$info = get_browser(null, true);
```

It will return an array with the browser information. You can use that information to build the proper link from the server side. See the documentation for details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: What are the limitations of this?  Seems to me browser sniffing can't work efficiently if its server-side.

Comment: @Zach L It works as bad as client side browser sniffing as it relies on the information, that a browser sends with the HTTP headers. This is not reliable at all – as are any browser sniffing techniques. For example Opera has a button to switch as which browser it should identify itself to a server; some clients also send the footprints off multiple browsers at once.

Comment: The user agent header can always be spoofed, that's the limitation.

Answer (score 2):

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
    var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
    if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
    M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];

    return M;
})();
```

THIS IS NOT MINE! It was posted by @kennebec on this other question:
[jQuery browser detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498057/jquery-browser-detection)

Comment: Since OP didn't specify jQuery, we probably shouldn't assume he wants to use it.

Comment: Ok, check this one then, it's pure JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect Internet Explorer, You have to read about [**conditional comments**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Conditional%20comments&oq=Conditional%20comments). You do not need Javascript at all.

You can write:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<a href="ielink">some text</a>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> -->
<a href="otherlink">some text</a>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: uhmmm, that will detect Internet Explorer, but thats it, unless I'm confused.

Comment: Oohhh, but your syntax on the `if !IE` looks wrong.  It should be `<!--[if !IE]><!-->...<!--<![endif]-->`

Comment: Point of interest, [IE-10 is apparently dropping support for conditional comments](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/)