# Negative margin in Safari shows different result than other browser like Firefox

Tags: html, css, safari, margin

I have specified negative margin-top for some link within heading for responsive look. However, same property doesn't work for Safari, text gets overlapped. On removing that property, look is proper. But adjustment in one browser breaks the design in other browser. So how to deal with negative margin. Code is something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <h4 class="txtalign">
         <a href="aaaa.com"></a>
      </h4>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
h4.txtalign{
   margin:-25px 0 6px 8px;
   font-size:22px;
   font-family:"Arial,Verdana";
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the full CSS code and the expected result. Maybe in a fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

You need to tweak the CSS for browsers with and without the affected properties. This answer has some info on how to do that:
[jQuery browser detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498057/jquery-browser-detection)

Comment: There are probably CSS solutions to this problem. Managing different CSS for modern browsers (modern = not older IEs) should only be used as a last resort