# How can I show a message when IE is used to access a site?

Tags: browser

Our employees have to access various vendor websites. One is optimized for Chrome. How can I give them a message in IE when they use IE to access this site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery browser detection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498057/jquery-browser-detection)

Comment: Not a duplicate what I would like to do is display a message on the users machine that this URL is optimized for Chrome please use the Chrome browser

Comment: Do you have control over that vendor website? Can you change the code of that website? If not, you're pretty much out of luck. If yes, read that link Jake Chasan has posted and try to find a solution. If you are having problems with this part, post your code and the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't have any control, guess I will just have to do it old school and print some instructions